# Flow and Javascript . Cannot call function because property is missing in object type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Using flow type checker to type hint my javascript code

```
const functionName = (name: string, newvalue:string , units: {}) :{} =>  {

  //Obj to be returned
  const returnObj = {};


  //index of a event.target.
  const indexofChange: number = units.findIndex(matchElement, {
    name: name
  });

  ....
  ....
}
```

Flow is giving me an error

**Cannot call units.findIndex because property findIndex is missing in object type [1].**

Comment: [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is an array method. It doesn't exist on regular objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tholle

```
const functionName = (name: string, newvalue:string , units: Array<Object>) :Array<Object> =>  {

  //Array to be returned
  const returnArray:Array<Object> = [];


  //index of a event.target.
  const indexofChange: number = units.findIndex(matchElement, {
    name: name
  });

  ....
  ....
}
```

fixes this